# Eclipse Code Style not reflecting in project

Tags: java, eclipse

```
Eclipse Code Style.
```

I want to use prefix `data_` with my some String fields .

I followed this link

http://maffelu.net/eclipse-adding-prefix-rule-for-fields/

and i set field `data_` in prefix column .

i typed `public String somevalue`;

but there is no  prefix added.

please assist me .

Answer (score 2):

The prefix rules govern the generation of getters/setters. So if you define your prefix as `data_`, and add a variable to your class called `data_age`, the generated getters/setters will be `getAge` and `setAge` respectively.

In other words, you still have to type out your variables, the IDE is not going to do it for you.

Comment: Yes, it allows you to customize how getters/setters are generated.

Comment: ok i got you . i ll have to type the variable name but in getter/setter it ll automatic remove the prefix..thanks